# can not generate mailer using rails generate mailer MyMailer in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

```
D:\rail_test\emails>rails generate mailer MyMailer
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.11/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:438:in `method_missing': undefined method `server_settings=' for ActionMailer::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
    from D:/rail_test/emails/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in 'require'
    from script/rails:6:in '<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your config/environment.rb file you probably have something like:

```
ActionMailer::Base.server_settings =
```

That should be:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings =
```